# Should I continue to use Socket.io?

Tags: ios, sockets, socket.io

I am currently in the process of writing an iOS app and it's now been decided that there will no longer be an in-built real time messaging service. This was the main reason around using Socket.io on the server. So basically when the app is loaded it logged in in the background by sending the login credentials with the connection request. Now that I don't need the messaging service, most of the app is just information requests and the server responds with the relevant information. I could still utilize the real time aspect by sending updated information to the device if it gets updated on the server and some in-app notifications could utilize this too. However I'm pretty sure it can be all done using http requests and I'm not sure how likely I would need real time functionality in a future update.

Ignoring time and money, should I fundamentally re-write the way the server and the app communicate or would it be okay to continue using Socket.io and websockets?